# d3.select doesn't work well?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I'm using d3 trying to change properties in a c3 graph, the only way I can detect the element is by its css property : "text.c3-chart-arcs-title".
The page has two elements with the css property, and the function is called 2 times in order to get to both elements. 
My code is :

```
if(d3.select("text.c3-chart-arcs-title")){
       let vari = d3.select("text.c3-chart-arcs-title");
       console.log("got here");
       vari.attr("id", "title" + name); //name is a variable that must be different between both elements
       vari.attr("class", "substitute"); //I replace the css to be able to get to the second graph
                }
```

However only the first element is affected by my change, the second doesn't even though I have 2 times "got here" meaning the second element is detected.

Note: I will use these two components afterwards by using :

```
$("#title" + name).css('cursor', 'pointer')
                    .click(function () {
                        //function using variables of each component 1 and 2 previously selected 
                        }
                    });
```

Could you please tell me what I did wrong and how to access the second element ?
Thank you for your help,

Comment: *"However only the first element is affected by my change, the second doesn't even though I have 2 times "got here" meaning the second element is detected."*... No, it's not: you're just selecting the first one **twice**. Just use `selectAll`: https://jsfiddle.net/vhxrou8o/

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thank you for your answer, however I can't use SelectAll since I need to have different names for the id (that I use afterwards) and the name depends of parameters called in the function (that I call twice now). 
My question is : the class "text.c3-chart-arcs-title" is replaced by the class "substitute" so logically it won't be detected the second time

Comment: For proper help please post a [MCVE]. If that is a function that you call twice (it's not exactly clear in your code) it will change the class of both elements: https://jsfiddle.net/c5yqop10/

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I added the other code (I didn't put it earlier because it's not relevent to the issue). yes, I don't mind modifying both classes.
What I need is :  
1/ detect the first element and give it an id that will be detected later for the function. 
2/ Then, the second time detect the second element, assign a different id and do the treatment for the second element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have some pre-existing elements that share the same class and are hoping to assign new id's to them based on their order in the DOM.

You only have two elements, but are essentially doing a loop to select each element individually. This is not really the "d3 way" of doing things, loops are unnecessary for many common tasks with d3.

Let's select all the charts at once and assign new properties to all elements at once. There are two ways we can do this:

- assign a new id based on the index of each element
- assign a new id based on data we bind to the selected elements

Method one is fairly straight forward:

```js
// select all charts and give them an id based on their index:
d3.selectAll(".chart")
  .attr("id", function(d,i) { return "Chart"+i; });
  
// adding buttons for demonstration:
d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data([0,1,2])
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .style("cursor","pointer")
  .text(function(d) { return "Chart:" + d; })
  .on("click", function(d) {
    d3.selectAll(".chart")
      .style("background-color","white");
    d3.select("#Chart"+d)
      .style("background-color","yellow");
  });
```

```css
.chart {
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<div class="chart">This is Chart 1</div>
<div class="chart">This is Chart 2</div>
<div class="chart">This is Chart 3</div>

<p> Select a div: </p>
```

But, so is method two, which also allows you to specify specific names easily for your charts:

```js
// deterimne some id's beforehand
var names = ["Chart1","Chart2","Chart3"];

// select all charts and bind the id array to it
// then set the id of each chart based on the bound data:
d3.selectAll(".chart")
  .data(names)
  .attr("id", function(d) { return d; });
  
// and buttons for demonstration:  
d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(names)
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .style("cursor","pointer")
  .text(function(d) { return d; })
  .on("click", function(d) {
    d3.selectAll(".chart")
      .style("background-color","white");
    d3.select("#"+d)
      .style("background-color","yellow");
  });
```

```css
.chart {
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<div class="chart">This is Chart 1</div>
<div class="chart">This is Chart 2</div>
<div class="chart">This is Chart 3</div>

<p> Select a div: </p>
```

---

Your approach can work, it is superficially modified below (which makes the question's stated problem un-reproducable, but it is a bit of an x,y problem in that your issue likely is really how to accomplish the result *("how to access the second element"*), rather than what is wrong with the code), but your chosen approach is a little outside of the usual d3 approach. Here is your code working as intended:

```js
var names = ["chart2","chart1"]

function test() {

  if(d3.select(".chart")){
       let vari = d3.select(".chart");
       console.log("got here");
       vari.attr("id", names.pop()); 
       vari.attr("class", "substitute"); //I replace the css to be able to get to the second graph
                }
}

test();
test();

d3.select("#chart1")
  .style("border","1px solid black");
  
d3.select("#chart2")
  .style("background-color","#ccc");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<div class="chart">Chart 1</div>
<div class="chart">Chart 2</div>
```

Comment: In my humble opinion this is a XY problem that will unfold forever.... But let's see what happens.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, yeah, not sure why I hedged on that, it is an xy problem. The non-canonical approach in the question just weighed too much on me though and I had to throw out an alternative path to the goal.

Comment: thank you @AndrewReid for the answer, I found out that there was nothing wrong with my code, I ended up using SelectAll